# How to use Zabbix's CurlHttpRequest() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, http, curl, request, zabbix

I am learning Zabbix. I would like to use CurlHttpRequest() and all these functions: [image]

I can't find the documentation (what's going on inside). I would like to run a JavaScript script on my computer. How can I do that? I have a problem that even this simple line of code is undefined:

```
var req = new CurlHttpRequest();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you are configuring javascript in zabbix media types, you have an option to test the script.

```
var response,
    json_payload,
    params = JSON.parse(value),
    wurl = params.URL,
    msg = params.Message,
    request = new CurlHttpRequest();
    
    json_payload = '{"attachments": [{"text": "' + msg + '"}] }';

    Zabbix.Log(4, '[ cURL-log ] Sending request: ');

    request.AddHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
    response = request.Post(wurl, json_payload);

    Zabbix.Log(4, '[ cURL-log ] Received response with status code ' + request.Status() + '\n' + response);
```

you cab use Zabbix.Log to generate logs like console.log in javascript.